# How to purge incoming Xbee packets from the buffer?

Tags: xbee

I have a need to receive a specific confirmation packet after commanding my transmitting Xbee to stop sending normal packets.

My buffer still has normal packets in it when this happens, so next time I call readPacket(), I don't want to see them. So right before I call my stop command, I try to purge the incoming buffer like this:

```
void burnSerial(void) {
  while (xbee.readPacket(20)) {
    xbee.getResponse().getRx16Response(rx16);
  } //read all available responses
    // only do this when not in a constant stream of responses or it may hang.

  while (Serial.available()) { Serial.read(); }
  //burn whatever may be in serial buffer
}
```

But this doesn't work. The next time I call `xbee.readPacket()`, I see tons of normal packets before I finally see my confirmation packet. Why don't these functions do anything for me at all?

Answer (score 1):

It means there's a lot of latency between your issuing a command and getting a confirmation of the command's effect. When you send the command, it's best that you wait and read packets *until* you find the confirmation and *then* you return from the function or do whatever else you want to do. There is no need for a separate `burnSerial()` function, nor should you blindly discard data. So basically, the sequence of operations should be:

- Send the command
- Read packets until you find the 'confirmation' identification marker
- Return or exit

This assumes that your transmitter only sends confirmation *after* it has halted the stream.